# Nasm "instruction expected" problem is it my compiler or my code

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am fairly new to NASM and I already want to blow my brains out because I dont know why I keep getting this error "instruction expected" Line 14.  Is it my compiler or my code.  Please help me Ive been at this for hours and I don't know what to do at this point.

```
section .data
  CELC DB ?
FARH DB ?
MSG1 DB 'INPUT VALUE OF CENTIGRADE','$'
MSG DB 'EQUIVALENT FARHRENEHEIT IS','$'

section .text
    global _start
section .code

_start:
    ASSUME CS:CSEG, DS:DSEG
       MOV AX,DSEG
       MOV DS,AX ; INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT
       LEA DX,MSG1
       MOV AH, 01H
      
       INT 21H ; DISPLAY "INPUT VALUE IN CELC"
       MOV AH, 01H
      
       INT 21H ; INPUT VALUE IN CELC
       MOV CELC,AL ; MOVE THE INPUT VALUE TO 'CELC'
       MOV AL,CELC
       MOV CL,09H
       MOV CH,00H
       MUL CL ; AX=9*CELC
       MOV CL,05H

       DIV CL ; AL=AX/CL=(9*CELC)/5
       ADD AL,20H ; ADD 20H=32 TO AL TO GET FAHR
       MOV FARH, AL ; FAHR=(9*CELC)/5+32
       MOV AH,4CH
       INT 21H
```

Comment: This code is in MASM syntax so will need to be converted to NASM syntax. The other option is to assemble it with MASM or JWASM (an open source replacement for MASM available on Linux/Windows//MacOS/DOS etc). Note that this code is intended to run under DOS. Don't expect it will run on Linux or 64-bit Windows. It can run on 32-bit Windows because of the NTVDM component but it is still a DOS program.

Comment: If you want this code to run in Linux/64-bit Windows/OSX or some other OS you will need an emulator. DOSBox is a popular one for running DOS programs in a virtual x86 environment.

Answer (score 2):

Errors discovered in your code are almost never compiler bugs. Line 14 says  `ASSUME CS:CSEG, DS:DSEG` which is MASM way to tell assembler which segment registers it should use for addressing segments `CSEG` and `DSEG`. But instead of those segments (alias *sections*) you declared `.data`, `.text` and `.code`. Beside that, [NASM doesn't ASSUME](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.4). Comment out Line 14 and declare sections `DATA` and `CODE`, as is usual in DOS programs.

NASM requires references to the contents of memory variables be in square brackets.
Instead of
`MOV CELC,AL ; MOVE THE INPUT VALUE TO 'CELC'` you need `MOV [CELC],AL` etc. Or employ unused registers BX,SI,DI instead of memory variables. BTW its better to calculate temperatures as 16bit signed integers, otherwise you are restricted to the range 0..255 degrees.

Also revise [DOS function](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm) and concentrate to the proper function identificator in `AH` before `INT 21h`. You'll need `AH=09h` to display the prompt. Don't forget that when the user enters **5** on the keyboard, DOS function `AH=1` returns 35h in `AL`, which is not the value you should calculate with.

I recommend to start with some HelloWorld example, learn to use TLINK and TurboDebugger in DOSBox and only when all works, add more functionality, step by step.